# "rake aborted! stack level too deep" while deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise, cedar

My website used to be working and Heroku precompiled the assets and everything. Now, seemingly out of nowhere, I started to get this message on deploy:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
mkdir -p /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/public/assets/icons
mkdir -p /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/public/assets/icons
mkdir -p /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/public/assets
(in /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn)
mkdir -p /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/public/assets
mkdir -p /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/public/assets
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
(in /tmp/build_31cexir1p9pwn/app/assets/stylesheets/theme.css.scss)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
```

It can't precompile my css file.

I'm using cedar stack and this is my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'devise'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Here's my application.rb file

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

And here's my production.rb file

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Enable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will not need this)
config.serve_static_assets = true

# Set expire header of 30 days for static files
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"

# Allow JavaScript and CSS compression
config.assets.compress = true

# Compress JavaScript by removing whitespace, shortening variable names, ...
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

Now all my links to images are broken (I'm using image-url() in my css file). What could be the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: would you be able to list this file, theme.css.scss. It seems overflow with your asset pipeline

Comment: The "stack level too deep" error is, in effect, a case of the application running out of memory.  It's often a result of programs that use a lot of recursion (functions that call themselves), and things like parsers (SASS to CSS, CoffeeScript to JS, ERB to HTML) would typically use recursion.  As a work-around, try pre-compiling the assets before deploying -- you may have more memory on your local machine than the Heroku instance.

Comment: This is a pretty serious bug. Did you report it on github?

Comment: It had already been reported. That's where the answer was. https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/78

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was truly desperate so I [asked another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787766/rake-assetsprecompile-not-working-on-heroku). Apparently this is caused by sass and downgrading to sass-rails <s>v3.1.4</s> v3.2.5 will make it work.

Answer (score 1):

upgrading to sass v3.2.12 did the trick for me

but overall, it looks like the issue is fixed on all current versions, just do a bundle update and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

For ruby 2.3.0 or lower versions are having the following line in **application.rb** file for Rails. But 2.4.0 or higher have implemented those as automated.

`Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)`

Changing the ruby version to 2.3.0 did the trick. This one saved my day.