# assets:precompile stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to have success on running the task rake assets:precompile but I have the following error

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace

** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all 
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
  (in .../app/assets/stylesheets/admin/scaffolds.css.scss)
.....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:162
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/diogui/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/...]
.....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
.....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
.....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
....rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in    `    invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
```

In my production.rb I have

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Yes I have Sass 3.1.4

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Does anybody have an idea what is the problem ? Or what am I missing ? Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solved it?

Comment: how does your scaffold.css.scss look?

Comment: Same problem here, and only in the production environment.  I'll let you know if I figure it out.  I don't see any signs of infinite recursion in the scss file mine references... and it works fine in staging and development so it must be something to do with the environment.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a documented issue with the sass-rails gem: https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/78

It can apparently be solved by downgrading the sass-rails gem to 3.1.4 (if you're on Rails 3.1) or upgrading to 3.2.5 (if you're on Rails 3.2): ["rake aborted! stack level too deep" while deploying to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779456/rake-aborted-stack-level-too-deep-while-deploying-to-heroku)

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ruby version to 2.3.0 did the trick.
This one saved my day.