# rake assets:precompile fails after ruby 1.9.2 -> 1.9.3 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, precompile

I'm trying to precompile my app assets locally. When I run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
```

I get a stack level too deep error:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
  (in /Users/koriroys/source/side_projects/test_app/app/assets/stylesheets/favorites.css.scss)
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:170
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194...]
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `sh'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:40:in `ruby'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `call'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:228:in `block in execute'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `each'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:223:in `execute'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:166:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:159:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:152:in `invoke'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/koriroys/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

What's changed since `assets:precompile` worked: I moved from ruby 1.9.2 to 1.9.3. Not understanding why it says it's failing on a stylesheet. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried `bundle update rake`? I might even recommend a `bundle update` unless you have specific version dependencies.

Comment: @CyleHunter: 10.0.3 is the newest.  Also, it means that Rails are more less recent because they always depend on particular version of rake.

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys: p194 is outdated by few patchlevels.  What happens on 1.9.3p327?

Comment: Suppose I should add that I'm on Rails 3.1.1. And yes I've run `bundle update`.

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys: 3.1.1 is really old and this might be the problem.  Try updating to newest 3.1.x while being still on 1.9.2, check it, then try moving to 1.9.3 again.  Good chance that it helps.

Comment: Tried it with 1.9.3p327. Same issue. Going to try going back to 1.9.2 after gcc downloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the right thing to Google: "scss stack level too deep". Turns out it's a sass issue per this SO: ["rake aborted! stack level too deep" while deploying to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779456/rake-aborted-stack-level-too-deep-while-deploying-to-heroku)

TL;DR:

I had this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.1.4'
```

Needed this:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '3.1.4'
```