# Running assets:precompile just hangs, only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-admin

I don't know what's different now, but ever since a few days ago, running `rake assets:precompile` just hangs forever. This only happens when I set `RAILS_ENV=production`.

If I `tail -f` `production.log`, I can see this:

```
Compiled rails_admin/jquery.pjax.js  (0ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled jquery_nested_form.js  (0ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/ra.nested-form-hooks.js  (233ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled bootstrap.js  (10ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/ra.widgets.js  (240ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/ui.js  (100ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/themes/default/ui.js  (0ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/custom/ui.js  (0ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/rails_admin.js  (1121ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/jquery.colorpicker.css  (50ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/imports.css  (9460ms)  (pid 28704)
Compiled rails_admin/rails_admin.css  (9472ms)  (pid 28704)
```

Since `rails_admin/rails_admin.css` is the last thing that shows up, it seems like `rails_admin.css` might be the culprit. The only thing `rails_admin.css` does is include a file called `imports.css.scss.erb`, and if you [look at that file](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/imports.css.scss.erb), there's so much there that it could be pretty much anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update: making `rails_admin.css` not include anything *did* make precompilation work.

Comment: So set that as the answer?

Comment: Good idea. Added as answer.

Comment: Not to nag, but you might want to accept it too ;)

Comment: Get off my back!!! Just kidding. Accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `rails_admin.css` not include anything made precompilation work.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you upgraded to the latest 3.1.x version of Rails?  You might need to downgrade sass-rails to 3.1.4....

see this comment for more info... ["rake aborted! stack level too deep" while deploying to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779456/rake-aborted-stack-level-too-deep-while-deploying-to-heroku/9828925#9828925)

Comment: I upgraded to Rails 3.2.11, but I was having problems before that. Unfortunately downgrading `sass-rails` didn't seem to do the trick.